# sin_port in sockaddr_in

Tags: c++, c, linux, posix

Which port should I use if I need to get the hostname of an IP ? From where does getnameinfo() get the hostname ?

```c
struct sockaddr_in sa;
sa.sin_family    = AF_INET;
sa.sin_port    = htons(?); // which port ?
inet_pton(AF_INET, "x.x.x.x", &(sa.sin_addr));

char host[NI_MAXHOST];
getnameinfo((struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa), host, NI_MAXHOST, NULL, 0, NI_NAMEREQD);

puts(host);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use `serv` and `servlen` arguments, port number is irrelevant. Otherwise it's used to look up the *service* by the port number, something like `"ssh"` for port 22, `"smtp"` for port 25, etc. (see `/etc/services` for more).

`getnameinfo()` can get the hostname from a number of places (with `nsswitch.conf`, miscellaneous `libnss` modules can be enabled for different kinds of name resolution). On a typical desktop linux distro, I'd expect it to look at `/etc/hosts` first, then query DNS servers according to `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getnameinfo.3.html:

> The sa argument is a pointer to a generic socket address structure (of type
>   sockaddr_in or sockaddr_in6) of size salen that holds the input IP address and
>   port number.  The arguments host and serv are pointers to caller-allocated
>   buffers (of size hostlen and servlen respectively) into which getnameinfo()
>   places null-terminated strings containing the host and service names
>   respectively.
>
> The caller can specify that no hostname (or no service name) is required by
>   providing a NULL host (or serv) argument or a zero hostlen (or servlen)
>   argument.  However, at least one of hostname or service name must be
>   requested.

So, if you're only interested in the hostname, don't provide a buffer for the service name.

I'll defer to others on the topic of where this comes from, but the code is in glibc if you're curious.